# Can I read and overwrite using 'open' only once?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

There are 1000 over html files.

I want to do:

- read file.
- trim the specific line.
- over write the file (not appending).

following code worked. but I thought using 'open' twice was wasteful. Can I write more simply?

```
for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.html')):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as reader:
        html_ = reader.read()
        replaced = html_.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>", "")
        with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as writer:
            writer.write(replaced)
```

I tried:

- `'r+'`: this is addition.
- `'w+'`: `read()` method returned `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, open the file in `'r+'` mode, and 'rewind' ([seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) back to start) after reading:

```
with open(file_path, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    html_ = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    replaced = html_.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>", "")
    f.write(replaced)
    f.truncate()
```

I added a [`file.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) call as well, because you are removing data from the file. Without that call, you would not replace *all* data in the file, you'd still have `len(removed_data)` bytes at the end.

Your attempts failed because you did not seek back to the start when using `'r+'` (so writing started at the point where reading stopped, i.e. the end of the file), and `'w+'` truncates the file *first* (so sets the length to 0, dropping the contents).

The alternative would be to use the [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html); it lets you replace file contents in-place with a somewhat simpler approach:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(file_path, inplace=True, openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")) as f:
    html_ = f.read()
    replaced = html_.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>", "")
    print(replaced, end='')
```

With `inplace=True`, the old file is moved aside to a `<filename>.bak` backup for you, and printing directs output to a new file opened in the original location.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, wouldn't it better to use `FileInput` and change it in place?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: `FileInput` would create a separate file and move it over the old location. That's not necessarily more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. I see. I understood that when I call read(), the pointer progress. And when I call write(), writer start to write from that point. Thank you very much for your understandable explanations. I call truncate() also.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: the biggest issue with the `fileinput` module is how obfuscated the open procedure is, which makes specifying an encoding and error handler much harder than it needs to be. Try opening a file object in an encoding other than `locale.getpreferredencoding()` (which almost always is *wrong* on Windows, often wrong on others). I [wrote a replacement implementation](http://www.zopatista.com/python/2013/11/26/inplace-file-rewriting/) once.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: the module does have a helper function [`fileinput.hook_encoded()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.hook_encoded), and but only as of Python 3.6 can you specify an error handler without having to write your own hook.